# Where can I publish a .html website for free?

Tags: html

I have written an .html file with pictures and everything, and now I'm trying to publish it for free. I don't really care about domain names, i just want to publish it. Does anyone know how and where can I publish a website?

Comment: GitHub Pages is in style these days

Answer (score 2):

A great place is [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/)

You put your files in a repository and can publish it from there directly. Note you can only publish static websites.